# In HP Quality center 9.2, Manual run Popup window is coming but immediately minimizing and not able to open to execute the each steps of test case

Tags: manual-testing, quality-center

In HP Quality center 9.2, when start running the test set

In test lab module, Selecting the test case of test set  and click on Run->Manually Run.

then the 'Manual run:" Popup window is coming but immediately minimizing and not able to open to execute the each steps of test case.

Please help me if you know the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use multiple monitors? This answer assumes that you do. I have have had the same problem (with QC and other programs as well) when I used my laptop with an external monitor. If I closed out the popup with the secondary monitor in one position, but then repositioned my monitor configuration, the popup tries to open in a monitor that is no longer there.

**Example**
Say I have my laptop set as my primary monitor and an external monitor on the right. I run QC and the popup is closed out while it was displayed on the external monitor. Then I reposition my monitors so the external one is on the left. The next time i run a test in QC, the popup will try to open in the monitor on the right, even though there is no monitor there.

**Solution**
Ran a test in QC so that popup has opened. Then I opened my Graphics Properties (usually done by right clicking in the empty desktop and selecting Graphics Properties). In the graphics properties, I repositioned my external monitor to the right, left, top, and bottom until I found the popup. Then drag it to the primary monitor and close it from there. The next time it pops up, it will be on the primary monitor.

Answer (score 0):

http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-HP-Consumer-Products-and-Technologies/HP-Quality-Center-10-00-Manual-Runner-window-not-visible/m-p/572373/highlight/false#M3223

Had our TD Admin (QC Admin, ALM Admin) Delete my User name and re-add me back to Users and Groups.  This immediately resolved the issue.  Interestingly enough I had just moved to another building and repositioned my laptop's secondary monitor (before it was on the right of the primary and now it is above the primary).

HTH!
AHW

Comment: could you possibly add a little more information than simply a paste from the text of the HP forum answer, giving a bit more information? That would make your answer more useful to the person who asked the question.